# PHP & SQLite connect

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Ok so I'm getting an error for failing to connect to SQLite which is most likely from the mysqli_connect(). My question is what exactly is the user name and password, is it an administrative one or is this from the database? I'm new to database.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

"my_user" and "my_password" is suppose to be what exactly? I have localhost connected to 127.0.0.1 and "my_db" I just put as the database name I used and created.

Comment: MySQL and SQLite are different things and they use different functions. Look up SQLite in the PHP manual

Comment: Are you trying to use MySQL or SQLite?  The code looks like you're trying to use MySQL, which requires a server running somewhere, as opposed to SQLite, which just needs a file.

Comment: @kgraney This isn't SQLite? Oh man I thought I've been using SQLite this whole time. Especially with the "mysqli" part, I thought li = lite. Thanks!

Comment: Well, they both have `SQL` and an `i` in there.

Comment: MySQL `I` are the MySQL `I`mproved functions.  SQLite is a serverless file based database.

Comment: Can I use similar structure as MySQL? Or do I have to re-do my whole code for SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing `mysql` with `sqlite` and your connection using `mysqli()` command will not work then. You could instead use `open('nameofthedbfilehere')` open a stand alone file in `sqlite`.. See tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_php.htm).

Comment: Thanks! This was the reason, thank you for clearing it up. Are SQLite and MySQL functions the same but named differently? Or am I going to have to write my php file all over? I'm just trying to make a simple login script that will check the database for the user and compare the account name and password so it's not complicated but I just need to get a jump start if I need to write a new file.

Comment: No, they came from different (and therefore separate) class/library. You could re-write your php code but NOT ALL your php file but only the portion wherein you are going to use the sqlite database.

Comment: I might have to rewrite the whole thing since it was a checklogin.php script that grabs the username and password and checks the database to match it, if successful then it'll proceed but if not it'll deny access.

Similar to this checklogin, I don't think I could keep much if any from there. Good news is I can finally open my .db file perfectly fine now, now I just have to find out how to compare the usernames and passwords to the database.

Comment: Ok, if that's only the php you have then you could re-write that whole script. And good that you could open it already. Just look at the tutorial I gave you, specifically on `SELECT` part in order for you to use the table that you want only and then compare with values of your login and password from the user.

Answer (score 0):

User is the administrative user you made when you create the database.
And password is the database password you entered when you created the database.